# TollCosts not calculated

Tags: here-api

I asked about a thousand times for truck tollcosts. And they all return values.

Except this one: [Link](https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy&departure=2018-11-09T08:00:00&cost_optimize=1&driver_cost=25&vehicle_cost=0.5&currency=EUR&rollup=none&detail=1&tollVehicleType=3&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&height=4.0m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=40.0t&limitedWeight=40.0t&disabledEquipped=0&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=10&commercial=1&shippedHazardousGoods=2&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&waypoint0=geo!51.3,6.8&waypoint1=geo!42.6,-1.99&metricsystem=metric&maneuverattributes=notes,li&routeattributes=gr,lg&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&jsonattributes=41&combinechange=true&linkattributes=le,fl,rt&legattributes=mn&language=en-us)

In the warning section I get a couple of dosins errrors like: "context : "Route link id -50964891 not found in map. This might be a mismatch between map releases. Ignoring it for toll cost calculation.""

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the warning section this is due to the mismatch between map releases. 
Fleet Telematics api uses Routing API internally when you set attribute cost_optimize = 1 in your query. Since the two APIs have their own release cycles there could be a mismatch in the link Ids (only for a short period though). In your case, we don't see the link Id mentioned anymore in the response. You could try using other cost_optimize attribute options. Please read in the developer site for more information. Happy Coding!